# Finding probability involving dependent random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, random-variable, uniform-distribution

Suppose train on line A arrives in time uniformly distributed between 0 and 4mins, train on line B arrives in time uniformly distributed between 0 and 6 mins, and furthermore the time interval between A and B arrival is uniformly distributed between 0 and 4.

a. What is the probability train on line A arrives first

b. What is the probability you wait less than 2 mins for one of the trains to arrive.

Here's how I approached this question,

Let $A : $ arrival time for train on line A $\sim U(0,4)$,
$B : $ arrival time for train on line B $\sim U(0,6)$

and it is given that $A-B \sim U(-4,4)$

a. $P(A<B) = P(A-B<0) = \frac{1}{2}$

b. This is where I'm stuck, $P(\mathrm{min}(A,B) \leq 2) = 1 - P(A>2, B>2)$

But I'm not sure how I'd go about computing $P(A>2, B>2)$ any help or hint is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I believe there cannot exist any distribution with the properties you describe.

Comment: Interesting, can you elaborate more, what makes you believe that ?

Comment: Hint: Write $B=(B-A)+A$ and check whether or not the marginal distribution of $B$ can be uniform.

Comment: Wait, I am not the most proficient at this, but I thought the underlying question was to find a joint distribution and a conditional distribution such that 
$P(A) = \frac{P(A,B)}{P(A|B)}$ 

Am I understanding something wrong? I thought that the expression $B = (B - A) + A$ would not hold only under independence. but if B depends on A, is there a way it can hold?

Comment: I actually thought that there would be infinitely many possibilities, but still I have no clue on how to find one of those that satisfy the requirements.

Comment: B = (B-A) + A of course always holds, and @whuber is right you cannot have distributions satisfying these conditions, and it just seems to me that problem statement isn't stated very well

Comment: In a [linked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/641710/an-impossible-distribution) the easiest route is to say you should have $E[A-B]=E[A]-E[B]$ by linearity of expectation but here $0 \not = 2-3$